# Insert using Dapper on asp.net core

Tags: sql, dapper

```
using (IDbConnection dbConnection = openConnection)
{
    string uQuery = "INSERT INTO User (Email, UserName, Password)"
                    + " VALUES(@Email, @UserName, @Password)";
    dbConnection.Open();
    dbConnection.Execute(uQuery, User);
}
```

I'm getting a **sql exception: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.** on the db.Connection.Execute statement.  I get the same error even if I omit the User parameter of the statement.  Am I doing the insert wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User is a reserved work in SQL server. Wrap User between brackets as `[User]` to solve.

Reference Reserved Keywords in SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Hope this helps.